# SELECT on a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

i'm a Postgresql beginner. I Have a table "crashs" with

ID | Date | Time

With ID as PK.

I have a query which is counting all crashs per day :

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(crashs.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "date", COUNT(crashs."ID") AS "nbCrashs"

FROM        crashs

WHERE       crashs.date >= to_date('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
        crashs.date <= to_date('2016-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD')

GROUP BY    crashs.date
ORDER BY    crashs.date ASC;
```

and the result :

```
    date       |  nbCrashs
----------------------------
 29/03/2016    |     2
 30/03/2016    |     4
 31/03/2016    |     3
```

Now i want to select the maximum nbCrashs of this query (so here, 30/03/2016 --> 4)

i tried a SELECT on this as a subquery but it don't works... Here is the query i tried :

```
SELECT      MAX(CrashsPerDay.nbCrashs)

FROM

(SELECT     TO_CHAR(crashs.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), COUNT(crashs."ID") AS "nbCrashs"

FROM        crashs

WHERE       crashs.date >= to_date('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            crashs.date <= to_date('2016-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD')

GROUP BY    crashs.date
ORDER BY    crashs.date ASC) AS "CrashsPerDay";
```

I am french so i'll try to translate the error message, but i got something like "missing entry of the FROM clause for the table "crashsperday"

The error point on my SELECT, on the 'C' of "max('C'rashsPerDay.nbCrashs)"

Someone know how to repair my query ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: What if more than one day has the maximum number?

Comment: I wonder if you need to alias: TO_CHAR(crashs.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: The GROUP BY is used to count the number of crashs per day, if i delete this, i will have something like :

29/03/2016   |   1
30/03/2016   |   1
30/03/2016   |   1
30/03/2016   |   1
31/03/2016   |   1
31/03/2016   |   1

For the alias, i come from SQL Server so i have some difficulties, but all my alias are functionnal with quotes. But you are right, i can use "SELECT Max(nbCrashs) but i get the following error : "NbCrashs don't exists"

Comment: @Gordon, this query will return the Max, even if more than one has the max. It will just return this max

Comment: @David sure i don't, i just add it for a better comprehension for you on the first query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case sensitivity problem. As soon as you start wrapping your names in `"Quotes"`, you have to be careful to always wrap that name in quotes every time you reference it. I.e. the following query will fix the issue for you:

```
SELECT      MAX("CrashsPerDay"."nbCrashs") -- Fix here
FROM  
(SELECT     TO_CHAR(crashs.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), COUNT(crashs."ID") AS "nbCrashs"
FROM        crashs
WHERE       crashs.date >= to_date('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            crashs.date <= to_date('2016-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY    crashs.date
ORDER BY    crashs.date ASC) AS "CrashsPerDay";
```

Or, perhaps better:

```
SELECT      MAX(CrashsPerDay.nbCrashs)
FROM  
(SELECT     TO_CHAR(crashs.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), COUNT(crashs."ID") AS nbCrashs -- fix here
FROM        crashs
WHERE       crashs.date >= to_date('2016-03-28','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            crashs.date <= to_date('2016-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY    crashs.date
ORDER BY    crashs.date ASC) AS CrashsPerDay; -- and fix here
```

In other words:

- These two names are the same (case-insensitive): `CrashsPerDay` and `crashsperday`
- These two names are not the same (case-sensitive): `"CrashsPerDay"` and `"crashsperday"`
- In PostgreSQL, these two names are the same (lower-case by default): `crashsperday` and `"crashsperday"`

OCD bonus fix: [It's "crashes", not "crashs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU-OycAb_Lg) ;-)